# Immediate Action Required – SSL 3.0 vulnerability

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I got this email from paypal, but I don't understand what they are trying to say ,

which service they are stopping from 3ed december 2014 ,

I am using express checkout process in payment for my site

do I need to purchase new SSL  ?

```
Immediate action required

XYZ,

On October 14, 2014, details were released about a vulnerability to
version 3 of Secure Sockets Layer (SSL 3.0). Since that time, PayPal has
been hard at work to mitigate any potential impact to our consumers and
merchant customers.

To help mitigate risk associated with this vulnerability, PayPal will
discontinue support for SSL 3.0 on DECEMBER 3, 2104 AT 12:01 A.M.
PACIFIC STANDARD TIME. Unfortunately, this necessary step may cause
compatibility problems resulting in the inability for customers to pay
with PayPal on your site or other processing issues.

We wouldn't have been able to extend our support of SSL 3.0 to December
3, 2014, at 12:01 a.m. PST if we hadn't also been able to take
significant steps to migrate the risk of this vulnerability for our
customers. We want to assure our customers we have seen no evidence that
the SSL 3.0 issue has led to any compromise of security at PayPal.

Keeping our customers' accounts, data and money secure is PayPal's top
priority and a guiding principle when we make challenging decisions,
like this one.

We're here to help our merchants through this process. We've put
together a comprehensive Merchant Response Guide [1] to ensure systems
are secure from this vulnerability.

WHAT DO I NEED TO DO?

If you don't manage website integrations for your business, we strongly
encourage you to work with your website service partner (developer,
hosting company or e-commerce platform, etc.) and share the Merchant
Response Guide [1], which provides the basic guidelines on how to update
to Transport Layer Security (TLS). If your website service has questions
or need support, advise them to contact our Merchant Technical Support
[2].

Thank you for your prompt attention to move this issue and understanding
of our approach. Though we recognize this necessary step may cause
compatibility issues, we can't stress enough that this short-term
inconvenience is heavily outweighed by our joint promise to our
respective customers that we will keep their accounts and financial
details safe. We plan to keep our customers up to date on how we are
addressing this issue via the appropriate channels, including PayPal
Forward [3], our Twitter handle [4], Customer Service [5] and for
merchants, through our Merchant Services team.

For technical assistance, please call 855-489-0342.

We appreciate your patience and understanding as we work around the
clock to better serve you and keep you and our consumers safe.

                 Help [6] Contact [7]Fees [8] Security [9] Features [10] Shop [11]

Please do not reply to this email. We are unable to respond to inquiries
sent to this address. For immediate answers to your questions, visit our
Help Center by clicking "Help" on any PayPal page.

© 2014 PayPal Inc. All rights reserved. PayPal is located at 2211 N.
First St., San Jose, CA 95131.

Call
Send SMS
Add to Skype
You'll need Skype CreditFree via Skype

Links:
------
[1] https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1147
[2] https://ppmts.custhelp.com/
[3] https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Forward/bg-p/PPFWD
[4] https://twitter.com/AskPayPal
[5] https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/
[6] https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_help
[7] https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_help&t=escalateTab
[8] https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees
[9] https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-safety-and-security
[10] https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/about-paypal-products
[11] https://shopping.paypal.com/index
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the issue is related to POODLE Vulnerability, which is causing us to disable SSLv3 based verification when you make a call to PayPal APIs.

When you make a request to PayPal APIs, the system tries to make sure that you are actually talking to PayPal, and not someone else. For that, we used to encrypt some data using SSLv3 protocol. Now, as Google Found the bug with SSLv3, we are upgrading to TLSv1.

For that you need to follow the steps shown in https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1182

Based on what language you are working on, the changes may be different. The fix is fairly simple, however, it is a good time to upgrade the entire SDK to latest version which may have more fixes and features.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your framework linked to the latest SSL implementation, you should be fine.

For example, if you have the latest version of OpenSSL 0.9.8 branch, it supports TLSv1 additionally to old protocols (including SSLv3).

If you have the latest of OpenSSL 1.0.1, it supports TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 additionally to old protocols.

But if you use something older without TLS support, then you have to upgrade in order to use it with PayPal.

AFAIR, PayPal Express Checkout allows you to have a button, so your buyers are getting redirected to PayPal site and process with their payments there. In this case all encryption is done by PayPal.
The trick is when buyers are coming back to your side to confirm the order. You need to make sure your site can talk to PayPal using https with TLS family of protocols.